# All sound in macOS virtual machines is white noise

Tags: audio, virtualization, vmware, sound-volume

I am running macOS virtual machines in VMware vSphere 7.0.3 (ESXi Host is a Mac Pro 5,1). I have everything from Snow Leopard to macOS Mojave - all of the VMs have this issue. This is fully supported by VMware and is also within the scope of the Apple EULA since I am using Apple hardware.

All of the machines have static / white-noise for any all sounds produced. Is there a fix for this? I am using the latest version of VMware Tools available. I cannot find any info on this issue online.

Comment: What host Mac, what macOS? vShpere is discontinued - see https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/88698

Comment: ESXi is enterprise virtualization that runs on Intel based servers (Dell, HP, etc.) If that is the case your question is officially off-topic (Virtualizing macOS on non Apple hardware). And honestly, that you got this to work at all is mildly surprising. Not surprised that some things just don't work.

Comment: @SteveChambers - EXSi will run on Mac Pro & Mac Mini, according to the linked post

Comment: Virtualizing macOS is still supported in vSphere 7.0, which is what I'm using. The physical Host is a Mac Pro 5,1 so all of this is in compliance with the Apple EULA and everything.

Comment: @SteveChambers, no, that's not the case. The ESXi Host is a Mac Pro 5,1.

Comment: Does sound work properly when bare metal booting macOS on the host?  If it does work, then the issue is how VMware is bridging the virtualized audio device with the hardware device.  It is likely the host OS (ESXi — Linux) doesn’t  have the correct drivers for the audio chipset.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. This Mac Pro 5,1 was running Mojave before I made it into a ESXi 7.0 Host. Yes, the audio worked fine when the machine had Mojave on it. Right, this is almost certainly an audio driver issue.

Comment: That, unfortunately, means it’s a VMware issue and outside our scope as we don’t have any VMware resources (links, downloads, etc.)  on this site.  Have you tried VMware support site or community forums?  Also, ESXi is basically a Linux distro.  Try to see which Linux distro they are using and run a version of that on bare metal to see if audio works.  If it does, then the issue is definitely how ESXi bridges the device. If not, then it’s a hardware incompatibility with the driver they are using.

Comment: Thank you, @Allan. I will try USB pass-through with a physical audio device.

Comment: The VMWare support articles doesn't list the 5,1, only the 6,1. idk what differs in the audio engine, but that may just be it.

Comment: Thank you, @Tetsujin. Good catch. I will look into driver differences between the Mac Pro 5,1 vs the 6,1 for ESXi 7.0.3